# Access the loop result to instance of class for output

Tags: c++, class, oop, for-loop, multiple-instances

Alright, so I have an class-inventory assignment for my C++ class. The thing I'm struggling with right now is the part between the loop and object creation.

```
string description = "";
int id_number{0};
int quantity_number{0};
double price_value{0};

for (int count{1}; count <= inventory_num; count++)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Item #" << count++ << endl;
    cout << "Enter the id number: ";
    cin >> id_number;
    cout << "Descriptiom: ";
    cin.get();
    getline(cin, description);
    cout << "Quantity on hand: ";
    cin >> quantity_number;
    cout << "Unit price: ";
    cin >> price_value;
    cout << endl;

}

InventoryItem item1(id_number, description, quantity_number, price_value);
InventoryItem item2(id_number, description, quantity_number, price_value);
InventoryItem item3(id_number, description, quantity_number, price_value);
InventoryItem item4(id_number, description, quantity_number, price_value);


item1.display(); cout << endl; 
item2.display(); cout << endl;      
item3.display(); cout << endl;
item4.display(); cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So the problem is, for example, looping the input for 4 times, but the output only shows the the data from the LAST INPUT OF THE LOOP for ALL OF THE OUTPUT`(item1,item2,item3,item4)`. How do fix this lads?

Comment: A variable such as `id_number` does not have different values depending on what was on your mind when you wrote it. You have learned about arrays or other kinds of collections recently. Read about them.

Comment: That's quite the definition of madness, writing the same statement 4 times and expecting different results ;)

You probably want to initialize one item per iteration of the loop using vectors and such things?

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the values in each loop iteration. After the loop the values of the last iteration are stored in your variables. You could fix it with a std::vector

```
#include "InventoryItem.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::getline;

int main() {
    string description = "";
    int id_number{0};
    int quantity_number{0};
    double price_value{0};
    std::vector<InventoryItem> items;
    for (int count{1}; count <= inventory_num; count++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Item #" << count++ << endl;
        cout << "Enter the id number: ";
        cin >> id_number;
        cout << "Descriptiom: ";
        cin.get();
        getline(cin, description);
        cout << "Quantity on hand: ";
        cin >> quantity_number;
        cout << "Unit price: ";
        cin >> price_value;
        cout << endl;
        items.emplace_back(id_number, description, quantity_number, price_value);
    }

    items[0].display(); cout << endl; 
    items[1].display(); cout << endl;      
    items[2].display(); cout << endl;
    items[3].display(); cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It works well, thank you. But can I ask what exactly emplace_back does in this case? Is it inserts a new element at the end of the vector, right after its current last element?

Comment: @FloydVu0531 it creates a new element at the end of the vector